# How to write http response from HttpClient to Serial monitor with a ESP32 (Wemos Lolin32)?

Tags: esp32

With my ESP32 Board, Wemos Lolin32, I would like to make a http GET request to "http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt", read the text file and print the text file to the serial monitor.

**The question is:** Why isn't basically the txt file written to the serial monitor? How can it be achieved? Do I need some kind of conversion of the char?

I am using similar code to that from this example https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient.
Basically the code can be reduced to this minimal example:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("SETUP FINISHED");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Connecting to httpClient");


 HttpClient httpClient;
  httpClient.get("http://arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt");
  while (httpClient.available()) {
    char c = httpClient.read();
    //Serial.print(c);
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

**The expected result is:** I would like to see the characters from the txt file (https://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt) in the serial monitor.

**The actual result is:** The connection to the WiFi can be established. In the serial monitor either question marks or strange symbols are displayed.

I have checked the baud and it is the same in the code and in the monitor. I tried to change this value, but it did not help.
[image: Serial monitor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching from HttpClient to HTTPClient and using String payload = http.getString(); Serial.println(payload); I can achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

it is `http://arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt`. without www. www is redirected to https. you can verify it from a browser

Comment: I have edited the URL, the result is the same.

Comment: `Serial.write(c);` if you `read` raw byte, then `write` raw byte. `print` converts number to text

Comment: The server also gzip encodes the content. He needs to add a `Accept-Encoding: identity` header.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Yes, I did change it to Serial.write(c);

Comment: It is pretty strange. Serial.write(c) and Serial.print(c) are producing exactly the same output.

Comment: When switching from HttpClient to HTTPClient and using String payload = http.getString(); Serial.println(payload); I can achieve the expected result.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43008)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, there is no link. it is the right URL to use in the sketch in question

Comment: @Juraj ... sorry I am wrong; I was under assumption the link itself was the answer. Upvoted instead now :-)